# Select string from text in batch

Tags: string, search, batch-file

I will give an example of what i need to do

Let's say i have this text file which contains a string

```
some text some text some text
some text some text some text
*****************************
Your info is  :  random_value
*****************************
some text some text some text
some text some text some text
```

I want a batch script to search through text and find the random_value and then return it into a variable.

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to SO. what is your question?

Comment: In other words: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have very low knowledge of searching and finding with batch scripting. I think i have to use tokens, but i am not sure, never tried it. @PA maybe i have not make my self clear. i need the batch script to search for the "your info is : " string and get the value between this string and the next blank character (next line character or enter)

Comment: What you are asking for could likely be accomplished with a combination of `findstr` and `for`.  Try `findstr /?` and `for /?` for more info to get going.

Comment: @lucas this is a good start, thanks. i will try findstr and see what i can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a pattern to match the line, and also a delimitter to split the matched string to get the desired value (If the string have spaces), you can do it with a FOR /F Loop:

```
@Echo OFF

Set "File=.\File.txt"
Set "Match=Your info is"
Set "Tokens=2"
Set "Delimitter=:"

For /F "Tokens=%Tokens% Delims=%Delimitter%" %%# in (
    'Type "%File%"^|FIND /I "%Match%"'
) Do (
    Set "Value=%%#"
)

Echo %VALUE%

Pause&Exit
```

PS: Tested with your example.

Comment: wow that's what i was expecting. i will try this. i really have to learn about the tokens and delims thing. you never let me down elektro. thanks ^^

Comment: i don't get the tokens thing. can you explain why u used tokens=2 ? and what is %%# doing? i tried with the example and didn't work, i also removed the spaces in "Your info is  :  random_value" and no success. thanks a lot

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html   I split the string in two parts (2 tokens), the first one before the ":" and the last after that delimitter. so in token 1 you will have "Your info is  " and in token 2 you will have "  random_value".

Comment: hey Elektro, can u please explain why you have to use ^| instead of | ? i finally made it work, thanks to you

Comment: @Futur because "|" is a operator, and "^" is the escape operator, you need to escape that operator inside the FOR command agrupation.